# Dynamic Django Model based on query

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Hello folks Im new to Django(I have just the finished the tutorial) but I think i understand the basic concepts of it .Im writing here because Im trying to do something "difficult"  for my current experience with django and searching the internet didnt give me a solution .What im trying to do is to create a dynamic model based on the number of entries of another model .To be more exact lets say i got the following model :

```
 class criteria(models.Model):
            criteria_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
            monotonicity = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=(('+','ASCEDING'),('-','DESCENDING')),default='+',verbose_name='Monotonicity')
            worst = models.IntegerField(default=0)
            best = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

What i want to do is create all the criteria models instances i want through the django admin panel and then query for all the creteria_text instances in the database and make a model with an attribute for every criteria_text instance.

So lets say I add the following criteria to the database(these are criteria_text attributes of criteria objects: Color,Weight,Price .

I want to end up with a model like this :

```
class Alternative(models.Model):
     Color = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     Weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     Price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The thing is that in my application this one has to happen a lot of times so i cannot make model each time someone adds an Alternative based on different criteria .

After searching i found that i can define dynamic models using the following format :

```
  attrs = {
        'name': models.CharField(max_length=32),
        '__module__': 'myapp.models'
    }
    Animal = type("Animal", (models.Model,), attrs)
```

So the question is how can I define "attrs" based on a query that gets all the criteria in the database ?Can i define a relationship of this dynamic model with another model ? Also the models already created should be updated if a user adds more criteria .

Is something like this possible ?
If so please show me the path .

Comment: I don't think defining dynamic models is a good solution here (or anywhere, really). Rather, you need a relationship that can have as many items as there are criteria instances.

Comment: Model class definition will not create any table in the database unless you migrate it.You can dynamically create class but any model operations will result error

Comment: @Daniel Roseman : Im a bit confused a relationship is to be written on a model right ?So I would still have to update the model itself .Also lets say, what you say works ,then I will have to manually add the value for every criteria line by line and also choose the criteria.What I was hoping for is to get the integerfields on a single line with the criteria texts above them .If Im missing something or Im off the road please stop me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think defining dynamic models is a good solution here (or anywhere, really). Rather, you need a relationship that can have as many items as there are criteria instances.

It might be something like this:

```
class Alternative(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    choices = models.ManyToManyField("Criteria", through="AlternativeChoice")

class AlternativeChoice(models.Model):
    alternative = models.ForeignKey('Alternative')
    criteria = models.ForeignKey('Criteria')
    value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The real logic will belong in the form, where you will need to create options for each criteria entry, and validate the AlternativeChoice dependent on the related criteria.